# Application of homogeneous version of Nakayama Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-modules, monomial-ideals

I'm currently stuck in the proof of Proposition A.2.3. on page 267 of *Monomial Ideals* by Herzog and Hibi.

First we consider the following commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F @>{\varepsilon}>> U\\
@V \alpha VV @VV \varphi V\\
G @>{\eta}>> V
\end{CD}
Here $U,V,F,G$ are $S$-modules, $S=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients over a field $K$. $F$ and $G$ are free f.g. modules, $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ are homogeneous surjective homomorphism with $\ker(\varepsilon)\subseteq\mathfrak{m}F$ and $\ker(\eta)\subseteq\mathfrak{m}G$, and $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the unique maximal omogeneous ideal of $S$.

On page 268, we consider the following commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F/\mathfrak{m}F @>{\overline{\varepsilon}}>> U/\mathfrak{m}U\\
@V \overline{\alpha} VV @VV \overline{\varphi} V\\
G/\mathfrak{m}G @>{\overline{\eta}}>> V/\mathfrak{m}V
\end{CD}
where the maps are the obvious one. By the costruction $\overline{\varepsilon},\overline{\varphi},\overline{\eta}$ are isomorphism, thus $\overline{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism. In order to complete the proof, one must show that $\alpha$ is also an isomorphism. The book only mentions that a homogeneous version of the Nakayama Lemma must be used. This is where I'm stuck.

This is the version I thought to use:

If $M$ is finitely generated graded $S$-module and $m_1,\dots, m_t\in M$ generate $M/\mathfrak{m}M$, then $m_1,\dots,m_t$ generate $M$.

I also know by basic tensor product isomorphism that $M/\mathfrak{m}M\cong K\otimes_S M$ for any $S$-module $M$. I don't understand how to use this to prove that $\ker(\alpha)=0$ for example.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the kernel and cokernel of $\alpha$ tensored with $K$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}$
Here's a useful corollary of homogeneous Nakayama:

> Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated graded $S$-module. Consider the
> finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $M/\m M$ and let $n$ be its
> dimension. Then $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ is a minimal set of generators of $M$
> iff $\{m_1+\m M,\ldots, m_n+\m M\}$ is a basis for $M/\m M$.

As $\bar\alpha$ is an isomorphism, it takes a basis of $F/\m F$ to a basis of $G/\m G$. Since $F$ and $G$ are finite free, the above corollary implies that $\alpha$ maps a basis of $F$ to a basis of $G$.